# Cannot bootstrap due to "maas" environment not found

Tags: juju, maas

I would like to test MAAS + JUJU + OpenStack (I followed the documentation on maas.ubuntu.org)

I already made a test environment:

- 1 MAAS server wich will also run JuJu
- 10 KVM servers for Openstack

The KVM servers are already in "ready" state in MAAS.

I would like to set up JuJu but i could not which is drives me crazy.

My environments.yaml:

```
environments:
maassrv:
type: maas
maas-server: 'http://${192.168.1.116}/MAAS/'
maas-oauth: 'my-key-from-maas'
authorized-keys-path: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
admin-secret: 1234
default-series: trusty
```

When I run `juju status -e maassrv` :

```
ERROR Unable to connect to environment "maassrv".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
environment "maassrv" not found
```

OK, it's right, so i should run `juju bootstrap -e maassrv`:

```
ERROR environment "maassrv" not found
```

When i run the command without the -e switch:

```
error: no environment specified
```

So, I am stuck here, I already added the required ssh keys to maas too. 
I ran out of ideas why it isn't working.

I did not use '${}' form in my config file (the forum did not allow me to post that line without it :) ). So it exactly looks like you adviced to modify.

When i run  `juju bootstrap -e maas --debug`

```
2014-06-10 08:34:11 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:302 running juju-1.18.4-trusty-amd64 [gc]
2014-06-10 08:34:11 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 environment "maas" not found
```

juju status -e maas --debug gives me this, this is OK, there is no maas environment...but i can't create is...it's a trap :)

```
2014-06-10 08:39:09 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:302 running juju-1.18.4-trusty-amd64 [gc]
2014-06-10 08:39:09 DEBUG juju api.go:179 no cached API connection settings found
2014-06-10 08:39:09 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 Unable to connect to environment "maas".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.
Error details:
environment "maas" not found
```

`Follow up:`

I managed to run `juju bootstrap` (had to create a maas user).
Which command failed again, so I had to run

`juju sync-tools --show-log`

Then rerun `juju bootstrap` which is failed again

The sympton: when I ran `juju bootstrap` it will pick up a random machine eg: maas-10, starts the machine and install the operating system, then swit it off and gave me this as result:

```
DEBUG juju.utils.ssh ssh_openssh.go:122 running: ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o "PasswordAuthentication no" -i /home/maas/.juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa -i /home/maas/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@192.168.200.114 /bin/bash
ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:123 bootstrap failed: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Stopping instance...
INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:113 Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:14 destroying environment "maas"
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 waited for 10m0s without being able to connect:    
Permission denied (publickey,password).`
```

It is weird, i added `maas` user's public key to `MAAS API` so that should be OK.
During the install process the installed server should import the key?!

Comment: Looks like you called your environment 'maassrv' so then you'd need to pass that to the juju bootstrap command. For example: juju bootstrap -e maassrv --debug

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the ${} from the maas-server address. It should then look like:

```
maassrv:
  type: maas
  maas-server: 'http://192.168.1.116/MAAS/'
  maas-oauth: 'your-key-from-maas'
  admin-secret: 1234
  default-series: trusty
  authorized-keys-path: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If that fails, run juju with the --debug and paste the output in your question. E.g. `juju bootstrap -e maassrv --debug`

Comment: I would like to know which authorized-keys-path did you use ?
id_rsa.pub come from your maas node or did you generate a key on your juju node ?